Svelte reactive prop not updating
I am trying to edit the contents of a component containing a text area, inside of a dynamic route. However this code does not update unless I refresh the page even if the variable is set reactively.
Here is how I define my variable
$: {
    variables = $config.stager.modules?.[$page.params.module];
}

When I display it on the page, it reactively updates like expected with no issues. However
<TextInput
    style="w-full"
    ,
    data={{
        label: variable[0],
        required: variable[1].required ? '*' : '',
        placeholder: variable[1].placeholder,
        value: variables?.[variable[0]],
        save_value: (value) => {
            setSubkey(config, `stager.modules.${$page.params.module}.${variable[0]}`, value);
        }
    }}
/>

When I try and set the "value" key, it doesn't update, and only updates if I refresh. What am I doing wrong?
I did see an answer on binding, but my component is rendered in an each loop:
{#each Object.entries(module_info.data.variables) as variable}

So Im not too sure how to go about doing it

Hard to tell where the problem could be from this little code. Please create a self-contained, minimal reproduction.

@brunnerh There is nothing else other than this, a svelte store inside a dynamic route. I'm sure its to do with the logic of the reactive variable but I have too many moving parts to recreate it

i think I've been in your shoes before - we had a similar issue with our company's browser where search results wouldn't update unless you reloaded the page.
anyway, we eventually figured out that redesigning the results page to be a single page (rather than separate components for each tag) made a big difference. not exactly a silver bullet, but it taught me the importance of getting reactivity and data flow
right.
in your case, it seems like the issue is with reactivity and value binding within your TextInput component. have you tried using Svelte's bind:value syntax? that might do the trick and ensure the value updates reactively.
